# MySQL Full Text Search sort by specific column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort my Full Text Search results by a specific column: `myRelevance`. In this column I assigned a "relevance score" (numbers from 1 to 1000) to every row. Now I simply want to sort my results by this column.

```
SELECT id, sku, name, myRelevance FROM products WHERE MATCH (sku, name, myRelevance) AGAINST ("searchTerm" IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY myRelevance DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

It somehow works. It ranks my results but not completely by `myRelevance`. Numbers are not 100% sorted DESC. There are still lower numbers higher up than higher numbers. I guess it has to do with the built in relevance score by Full Text Search?

How can I guarantee that it's 100% ranked by `myRelevance`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a stupid mistake. I do not need to include `myRelevance` to Full Text Search. Just sort by it.